# Trying to perform elastic-net regression in R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning-model, logistic-regression

I am new to R and Elastic-Net Regression Model. I am running Elastic-Net Regression Model on the default dataset, titanic. I am trying to obtain the Alpha and Lambda values after running the train function. However when I run the train function, the output keeps on lagging and I had to wait for the output but there is no output at all. it is empty.... I am trying Tuning Parameters.

```
data(Titanic)
example<- as.data.frame(Titanic)
example['Country'] <- NA
countryunique <- array(c("Africa","USA","Japan","Australia","Sweden","UK","France"))
new_country <- c()
#Perform looping through the column, TLD
for(loopitem in example$Country)
{
    #Perform random selection of an array, countryunique 
    loopitem <- sample(countryunique, 1)
    #Load the new value to the vector
    new_country<- c(new_country,loopitem)
}
#Override the Country column with new data
example$Country<- new_country

example$Class<- as.factor(example$Class)
example$Sex<- as.factor(example$Sex)
example$Age<- as.factor(example$Age)
example$Survived<- as.factor(example$Survived)
example$Country<- as.factor(example$Country)
example$Freq<- as.numeric(example$Freq)

set.seed(12345678)
trainRowNum <- createDataPartition(example$Survived, #The outcome variable
#proportion of example to form the training set
p=0.3,
#Don't store the result in a list
list=FALSE);
# Step 2: Create the training mydataset
trainData <- example[trainRowNum,]
# Step 3: Create the test mydataset
testData <- example[-trainRowNum,]

alphas <- seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1);
lambdas <- 10^seq(-3,3,length=100) 
#Logistic Elastic-Net Regression
en <- train(Survived~. , 
            data = trainData, 
            method = "glmnet", 
            preProcess = NULL,
            trControl = trainControl("repeatedcv",
                        number = 10,
                        repeats = 5),
            tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = alphas,
                                   lambda = lambdas)
)
```

Could you please kindly advise on what values are recommended to assign to Alpha and lambda? or what I am missing in the R code?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ is the regulation parameter. From the [`glmnet` vignette](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html#logistic-regression-family-binomial-):

> alpha is for the elastic net mixing parameter α, with range α∈[0,1].
> α=1 is lasso regression (default) and α=0 is ridge regression

With Lasso (using the L1 norm), feature parameters can become zero, which actually means dropping them out of the model.

$\lambda$ is a tunig parameter for the penalty term. Thus you need to tune $\lambda$ in order to find a good fit (i.e. proper "strength" of regulation). $\lambda$ needs to be tuned for every $\alpha$ (as different $\alpha$ actually gives a different model).

You may have a look at the [`glmnet` vignette](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html#logistic-regression-family-binomial-) or at [this article discussing the application Ridge in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/simple-guide-to-ridge-regression-in-r/).

Also see [Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf), Chapter 6.2 for details.